# Why enums with default values are not working as expected in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

I was going through Jon skeet website on C# Brain teasers http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html. Why item "Baz" is showing in the output even though I declared default values for all items in enum

---eg:1

```
class Test
{

    enum Foo { Bar, Baz,bread, jam };

    const int One = 1;
    const int Une = 1;

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
// output :Bar
```

--eg2

```
class Test
{
    enum Foo { Bar, Baz,bread=0, jam };

    const int One = 1;
    const int Une = 1;


    static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//output : Bar
```

--eg3

```
class Test
{
    enum Foo { Bar, Baz=0, bread=0, jam };

    const int One = 1;
    const int Une = 1;

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//output :Baz
```

--eg4

```
class Test
{
    enum Foo { Bar=0, Baz=0, bread=0, jam=0};

    const int One = 1;
    const int Une = 1;


    static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//output:Baz
```

Comment: If multiple enum members has the same value (0 in this case) - which one do you expect for enum with that value?

Comment: It's reverting to alphabetical selection. Baz is before Bread

Answer (score 5):

Enums *are just integers* to .NET. Any time you think of them as a name (like `ToString()`, you're *actually* saying "try to find a defined enum label that matches the 
integer value, and tell me the name of that". In this case, you have multiple enum labels with the same integer value, so which name in `WriteLine` is undefined. Note that `WriteLine` here is ultimately doing `f.ToString()`, which applies the "find a value" logic from above.

For `--eg5`, I would propose: `Foo f = (Foo)-1327861;`. Perfectly valid in .NET terms, but doesn't match *any* enum definition. It doesn't have to.

Comment: If I do what you told (Foo f = (Foo)-1327861).  I am getting compile error "Error CS0119 'Test.Foo' is a type, which is not valid in the given "

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the default values for your enum *members*, only for whole enum. Default value for it is `0`, which goes to first element of enum. Other enum members should differ from that value, otherwise they simply override it. In this case:

```
enum Foo { Bar=0, Baz=0, bread=0, jam=0 };
```

You're saying to compiler: OK, now they `0` will be named as `Bar`. Ok, now `0` will be named as `Baz`, and so on. It doesn't make any sence for compiler.

In a book [`Code Complete`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) one can find an advice to introduce a default enum member named like `None` and explicitly assign it to `0` and place it at first place of your enum. So, your code could looks like this:

```
enum Foo
{
    None = 0,
    Bar, // 1
    Baz, // 2
    bread, // 3
    jam // 4
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanx for answering. But, why only Baz is returning instead of any other item.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
enum Foo { Bar, Baz,bread=0, jam=0};

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)Foo.Bar);  // 0
    Console.WriteLine((int)Foo.Baz);  // 1
    Console.WriteLine((int)Foo.bread); // 0
    Console.WriteLine((int)Foo.jam);  // 0
}
```

So we can say that if we wont assign any integer values to the first item in the enum will be assigned with `0` and next item will be `previous item value + 1` if you assign some values then it will overwrite the default incremented values.

Take a look into [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ZoiUI)